# Summernote: How to enable the hyperlink "Text to display" field

Tags: javascript, summernote

I use summernote for a website. It works fine except for this:

When I create a new hyperlink simply by clicking on the link icon, I get that modal and I can create a new link, but I can't edit the "Text to display" field. It's disabled by the "disabled" HTML attribute. 
Even if I try to remove that attribute in the inspector, the field becomes obviously but the content of it is ignored.

I looked the doc and it seems not to exist a particular way to enable that. Maybe I'm wrong...

Here is how I initialize it:

```
$('.summernote').summernote({
        height: 200,
        toolbar: [
            ['style', ['style']],
            ['font', ['fontname']],
            ['size', ['fontsize']],
            ['text', ['bold','italic', 'underline', 'color']],
            ['height', ['height']],
            ['para', ['paragraph', 'ul', 'ol']],
            ['insert', ['link', 'video']],
            ['misc', ['fullscreen', 'codeview', 'undo', 'redo']]
        ]

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The Summernote editor's Link button appears to be designed to be clicked after text has been selected in the editor textarea.  The selected text then shows up in the Link modal dialog in the **Text to display** readonly textbox.  It can't be edited in the modal dialog.  If you need it to say something different, first edit the text you plan to select in the editor textarea, then select that text, then click the Link button.